# How to download an image with querystring in it

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to download and resize an image from the following url: http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/catalog/video.tvepisode.8D6KGWZK9B10/image?locale=en-CA&purposes=BoxArt.

It works fine when viewing it in a browser, but doesn't work too well when I download it locally. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$ curl -O http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/catalog/video.tvepisode.8D6KGWZK9B10/image?locale=en-CA&purposes=BoxArt

>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open(tmp_filename).convert('RGB')
```

How would I download the above file so that it can be processed as an image locally?

Comment: What happens when you try to open it locally?

Comment: You should consider using `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this with requests:

```
>>> res=requests.get('http://musicimage.xboxlive.com/catalog/video.tvepisode.8D6KGWZK9B10/image?locale=en-CA&purposes=BoxArt')
>>> res
<Response [200]>
>>> open('file.jpg','w').write(res.content)
```